# HVAC furnance runs for awhile, stops for 2 minutes, then starts back up and continues to heat until set point reached

Tags: hvac, thermostat, heating, central-heating, troubleshooting

I have a Carrier 58GS150 system.  At night it is set to 69.  In the morning it is set to 72. Recently, I replaced the air filter.  The system starts up fine in the morning and tries to reach 72.  Being that it is very cold outside, this takes some time.  Mid-way, the whole system will shut down for 2 minutes.  It will then start back up and continue to heat into order to reach 72. Sometimes one shut down is enough, sometimes it takes 2.  I don't think that I noticed this shut-down issue with the "dirty" filter. Any ideas what is happening??

Comment: What thermostat is controlling the system?

Comment: When it shuts off, is 24V present from R to C or not?